# Mysql : foreign key error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mysql version 5.5. I have two tables and i am tying to add foreign key constarint but somehow i keep getting this error that-:

Query I'm executing:

```
alter table ptcact add foreign key(ptcid) references ptccitation(ptcid);
```

Error I'm receiving:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'ptc_journal.#sql-496_34' (errno: 150)
```

My tables:

1. `ptccitaion` with `ptcid` as primary key with `storage engine = MyIsam`
2. `ptcact` with `storage engine=InnoDB`

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM doesnt support foreign keys.

See [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

Comment: I know that but i need MyIsam for full text support. My table ptccitation is MyIsam but the ptcact in which i need to enforce foreign key constraint is InnoDB.Is there a way to fulfil both conditions? @ardabeyazoglu

Comment: Mysql 5.6 supports innodb fulltext search. Thats your only option if you dont want to do extra job. Or you can use a 3rd party search engine for fulltext like sphinx and elasticsearch. They are far more capable than myisam fulltext.